# Is it possible to create API access for Google Search Console from Julia?

Tags: google-apps-script, search, julia

I've tried quite a few things so far.

I believe I'm om the right track but it still isn't working out for me.
I've created a service account and downloaded the json-file.

```
using HTTP
using GoogleCloud

creds = JSONCredentials("~credentials.json")

session = GoogleSession(creds, 
           ["webmasters","webmasters.readonly"])

site_url = "https://www.example.com"

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/$site_url/searchAnalytics/query?dimensions=query&rowLimit=10"

key = "xxxxxx"

headers = [
"Authoriazation" => "Bearer $key"
]


response = HTTP.post(url, creds)
```

Can someone help? Or tell me if it's even possible.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Not easy to help on this one given it requires setting up some sort of account I suppose?

Comment: Sorry. I have problems going through the OAuth2.0 flow. 
I should somehow require a access token but I'm not really able to do so.